# Are there any side effects to increasing the socket buffer size in Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets

I've been working on a large-file data transfer with 10 Gigabit Ethernet, and initially, I was having issues with UDP packets being dropped. After rewriting/optimizing a lot of my code, and developing new designs, I stumbled upon an article that discussed increasing the kernel socket buffer size. After doing so, I found that I could send many more packets without fear of any being dropped. Essentially, it seemed that I could eliminate packet loss, and increase transfer speed just by making the buffer size larger and larger (until I had something sufficient). However, my question is, does increasing the socket buffer size to something very large have any unwanted side effects? My first guess would be performance/CPU/memory issues, but in my testing, that hasn't really been a noticeable issue yet. Perhaps I'm just overly skeptical, but it almost seems too good to be true.

Comment: [Bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only side-effect is memory usage. Increase them gradually and monitor the system. As long as you leave enough memory for existing processes you should be golden.

Comment: does socket buffer occupy process's adress space?

Answer (score 1):

Refer http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/ link, it has useful basic information

Comment: Increasing buffer size may also result in  denying other incoming connection requests due to failure in memory allocation